# Nodejs application in docker swarm service, update has no effect

Tags: node.js, docker

Short and simple; **how do I update a replicated nodejs application in a docker swarm?**

Expected behavior: once update is triggered, the service receive some form of signal, eg: `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`

What actually happens: nothing... no signals, no updated service. I have to remove the service and create it again with the updated image.

I'm using [dockerode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode) to update the service. The documentation for the docker API, [of the subject in question](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ServiceUpdate), is broken *(one can not expand the sub menus for example: `UpdateConfig`)...* making it hard to know if I'm missing any additional specification.

If I run the command: `docker service update <SERVICE>` expected behavior takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ForceUpdate` flag must be increased by one each time you update... for the update to take place when you do not version your image.

```
    const
    serviceOptions    = { ... },
    service           = this.docker.getService(serviceName),
    serviceInspected  = await this.serviceInspector.inspectService(serviceName)

    serviceOptions.registryAuthFrom         = 'spec'
    // if we do not specify the correct version, we can not update the service
    serviceOptions.version                  = serviceInspected.Version.Index
    // it's not documented by docker that we need to increase this force update flag by one, each time we attempt to update...
    serviceOptions.TaskTemplate.ForceUpdate = serviceInspected.Spec.TaskTemplate.ForceUpdate + 1

    const response = await service.update(serviceOptions)
    response.output.Warnings && this.log.info(data.output.Warnings)
```

Still can't record a `SIGTERM` signal from the container, but at least now I can update my service